# Java can't call simple JDialog built using eclipse WindowBuilder

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm trying to make a custom JDialog using windowBuilder, but at the very beginning I faced some issues. So here they are:

I created simple Jdialog using windowBuilder. Here it's code:

```
public class GroupFrame extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GroupFrame dialog = new GroupFrame();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public GroupFrame() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
                okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
                buttonPane.add(okButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
            }
            {
                JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
                buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But then I want to change **public static void main(String[] args)** to something like **public void show()**.

The new show() method code is:

```
public void show() {
        try {
            GroupFrame dialog = new GroupFrame();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So when I'm triyng to call this changed method using the following code:

```
GroupFrame groupFrame = new GroupFrame();
groupFrame.show();
```

I've got the StackOverflowError (what a coincidence! ;D):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at UILayer.GroupFrame.<init>(GroupFrame.java:32)
    at UILayer.GroupFrame.show(GroupFrame.java:21)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at UILayer.GroupFrame.show(GroupFrame.java:23)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at UILayer.GroupFrame.show(GroupFrame.java:23)
    (etc...)
```

Could anybody point me on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the code of the show() method is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You construct a GroupFrame, and the call the show() method, which constructs another GroupFrame. This is already wrong. But it's even more wrong because then you call `setVisible(true)` which internally calls the `show()` method that you inadvertently overrode.

The show method should be named something else, and should be static:

```
public static GroupFrame createAndShow() {
    GroupFrame dialog = new GroupFrame();
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

This method would thus be called as this:

```
GroupFrame.createAndShow();
```

And please, don't catch Exception. And when you do it, don't swallow the exception.

Comment: Thanks, your post made everything clearer. And what's the problem with catching the exception? That's a bad practice?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad practice. Only catch exceptions that you can handle. If you can't handle it, let it go up the stack until it can be handled.

Answer (score 3):

> But then I want to change public static void main(String[] args) to
>   something like public void show().

You cannot do that, main method with the exact signature is the starting point of a Java program (for most of the cases but not all).

What you need is a separate `show` method which will make your dialog visible

EDIT:

Noticed your class extends `JDialog`, which means if you define show again, you are technically overriding the method present in `Dialog`, moreover show is deprecated.

From the docs:

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.5, replaced by setVisible(boolean).
>
> Makes the Dialog visible. If the dialog and/or its owner are not yet 
>   displayable, both are made displayable. The dialog will be
>   validated prior to being made visible. If the dialog is already
>   visible, this will bring the dialog to the front.
>   If the dialog is modal and is not already visible, this call will not return until the dialog is hidden by calling hide or dispose. It
>   is permissible to show modal dialogs from the event dispatching thread
>   because the toolkit will ensure that another event pump runs while the
>   one which invoked this method is blocked.

Instead use this:

```
public static void showMyDialog(){
    try {
         GroupFrame dialog = new GroupFrame();
         dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
         dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and in your main method you call `showMyDialog`.

But main method has to be present in your class if you want it to run as a **Java Application**, if some other class is going to call your show method then you dont need main method existence in your class.